# Firebase A/B test offline behavior

Tags: firebase-remote-config, firebase-ab-testing

I am doing a Firebase A/B split-test with Remote Configs.
When a user is offline does he get the different variations from the config files?
How is this recorded in the analytics?

Answer (score 1):

The initial default values are encoded in your application binary. Until you fetch updated values, the app will use these defaults. This includes if the app is unable to ever fetch updated values.

Once the app fetched values from the server, it stores those in local storage and uses those values next time it runs. So if your app is unable to fetch updated values afterwards, it uses the previous values that it fetched.

The app will always report its current values to Analytics, unless you explicitly log something else.

Comment: what if the fetched config is stale and no connection to the server can be established, are the defaults used again then or the stale ones?

Comment: There is no concept of a configuration being stale as far as I know. The defaults from the APK/API could just as easily be outdated, and RC has no way of knowing that. You can check it in your code of course, but it sounds more complex than it's typically worth (so reeks of a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).